# OnMouseOver works differently on same objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in Unity and I just found out a behaviour I do not understand...

I have a prefab "cell" that I made from a sprite and I want it to change its color when my mouse is over it.
So I added a `BoxCollider2D` component to it as well as the following script:

```c#
public class Cell : MonoBehaviour 
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }


    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.magenta;
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
    }
}
```

Then when I drag and drop the "cell" prefab to the scene, it won't work (when my mouse is over the cell, nothing happens).

Same problem when I add another "cell" prefab to the scene.

But when I add a third "cell" prefab to the scene, the feature works on the 2 first cells but not on the third.

I probably missed something or there is a behaviour I do not know, anyway if someone knows why this is happening, please tell me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code in my game using a 2d box sprite and it works fine.

Video > https://youtu.be/6GP3-aV9g3g

You may want to try a couple of things to debug it.

- First make sure that there is a `BoxCollider2D` and `Rigidbody2D` attached.
- Make sure that there is nothing covering the boxes in the scene.

When I am having trouble with an aspect of the game I try to break it down into its simplest components. Try making a scene with nothing in it apart from the box and trying it, if that doesent work, try attaching the scrip to a non prefab object.

Try adding `Debug.Log("Mouse Enter");` to the subs to check if the mouse is detected on enter, if it is detecting the mouse, maybe your spite renderer isn't working properly.

Try these things and let me know if they don't work, I would be happy to keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: Nice explanation. You mentioned trying it in an empty scene, I wanted to add that maybe some "invisible" objects are on the way of "cell". I suggest checking [raycast2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) for which object is on the way with the mouse.

Comment: I figured the problem: i had a background sprite with a box collider at the same Z-level than my cell. Thanks for the advice of using just an example as simple as possible for debugging, it helped !